# Adding a array of relative layout with a textview ans spinner to a linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a array of RelativeLayouts to one LinearLayout (ll) I have defined in my layout xml file.The number of relative layout elements I need to populate is totally dependent on the number of data I have in the DB. I just want a series of textview on the left hand side and a corresponding spinner on the right. The output I want is something like below:

[image]

But the below code is not doing the job for me. I get an empty screen, though the toast messages are being displayed, confirming that the loop is being executed completely. I am still new to android, and I am sure that I am missing out on something here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
    package com.gk.srmacads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class EditGrade extends Activity {

    dbOpenHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor c;
    String[] column ={dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID,dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SEM,dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBNAME,dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_GRADE};
    int len;
    RelativeLayout elems[];
    Spinner gradeSpin[];
    TextView tv[];

    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_grade);

        ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.egSem1);

        dbHelper=new dbOpenHelper(this);
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        c=db.query("ACAD_TABLE", column, null, null, null, null, null);

        len=c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(c.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        elems=new RelativeLayout[len];
        gradeSpin= new Spinner[len];
        tv=new TextView[len];
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvParam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        tvParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gradeAdap = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.grades, R.layout.spinnerlayout);

        int spinPos;
        for(int i=0; i<len ;i++)
        {
            elems[i]= new RelativeLayout(this);
            tv[i]= new TextView(this);
            gradeSpin[i]= new Spinner(this);

            tv[i].setId(1);
            gradeSpin[i].setId(2);

            spinnerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,tv[i].getId());

            elems[i].setLayoutParams(rlParam);
            tv[i].setLayoutParams(tvParam);
            gradeSpin[i].setLayoutParams(spinnerParam);

            tv[i].setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBNAME)).toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBNAME)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gradeSpin[i].setAdapter(gradeAdap);
            //spinPos=getGradePosition(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbOpenHelper.COLUMN_GRADE)));
            //gradeSpin[i].setSelection(spinPos);

            elems[i].addView(tv[i]);
            elems[i].addView(gradeSpin[i]);

            ll.addView(elems[i]);
            c.moveToNext();         
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_edit_grade.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
    android:id="@+id/egmainLayout">    

   <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/egSem1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">    
   </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u post complete classes andd xml with name?

Comment: I have added the complete class and XML file as well!

Comment: Im not sure it will fix the problem, but you're generating the same Id's (1,2) to the TV's and spinners in each row, try to assign a unique Id to each of view you're adding

Comment: Yeah, didnt fix the issue..but a valid point !

Comment: did u solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code i compiled at my end bascially i guess you did retrive data from cussor properly , below is code attached :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] column = { "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor", "Sit", "Amet" };
    int len;
    RelativeLayout elems[];
    Spinner gradeSpin[];
    TextView tv[];

    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.egSem1);

        len = 10;

        elems = new RelativeLayout[len];
        gradeSpin = new Spinner[len];
        tv = new TextView[len];

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        tvParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdap = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, column);

        int spinPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            elems[i] = new RelativeLayout(this);
            tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            gradeSpin[i] = new Spinner(this);

            tv[i].setId(i + 1);

            spinnerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv[i].getId());

            elems[i].setLayoutParams(rlParam);
            tv[i].setLayoutParams(tvParam);
            gradeSpin[i].setLayoutParams(spinnerParam);

            tv[i].setText("Lorem Ipsum");
            gradeSpin[i].setAdapter(arrayAdap);

            elems[i].addView(tv[i]);
            elems[i].addView(gradeSpin[i]);

            ll.addView(elems[i]);
            //c.moveToNext();
        }

    }

}
```

[SOURCE CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6q8uzh37ii93wi6/DyamicLay.rar)